# Extra linebreak in contenteditable after focus()

Tags: jquery, css

In Chrome/Safari with this JSFiddle test
http://jsfiddle.net/YLqqE/

If I type 'Hi' and press Enter, the text appears first in the Red box, then moves up to the blue one.

[image]

But, if I type 'Hi', click outside of the box to `blur()` it, then click back on the text and hit Enter, I get an extra space.

[image]

Why is that extra space showing up?  How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an easy fix. Just `return false` after a your logic for a return key, so the default action doesn't take place:

http://jsfiddle.net/YLqqE/2/

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 13:
        $('#msg').append(newEl.html());
        newEl.html('')
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  I was trying `e.stopPropagation()` and getting nowhere.  That was a quick response, I can't even give you a check for another 8 minutes.

Comment: No problem. And you were on the right track. An alternative to this is to add both `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter, a newline is added to the html of that div. To remove the newline from the div, remove it with a regular expression:
`$('#msg').append(newEl.html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""));`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HeAk7/)

Comment: No need to remove it. Just don't let it get added in the first place.